# How do I create a loop for reading lines then printing it out with a format (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop, format, readline

Hi I'm trying to create a readline loop and then print it out individually with a format but everytime i do it just repeats itself.
here is my code:

```
LF = open('fees.txt', 'r')
print('Now the final table\n')
print("Airline", format("1st bag",">15"),format("2nd bag",">15"), \
      format("Change Fee",">15"),format("Other Fee",">15"), \
      format("Feel Like",">15"),'\n')
line = LF
while line != '':
    line = str(line)
    line = LF.readline()
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    print(line, format(line,'>10'),format(line,'>15'), format(line,'>15'), \
          format(line,'>15'), format(line,'>15'),'\n')
LF.close()
print('===================================================\n')
```

and the result always turns like this:

```
Now the final table

Airline         1st bag         2nd bag      Change Fee       Other Fee       Feel Like 

Southwest  Southwest       Southwest       Southwest       Southwest       Southwest 

0          0               0               0               0               0 

0          0               0               0               0               0 

0          0               0               0               0               0 

0          0               0               0               0               0 

Yes!       Yes!            Yes!            Yes!            Yes!            Yes! 

JetBlue    JetBlue         JetBlue         JetBlue         JetBlue         JetBlue 

20         20              20              20              20              20 

35         35              35              35              35              35 

75         75              75              75              75              75 

125        125             125             125             125             125 

Yikes      Yikes           Yikes           Yikes           Yikes           Yikes 

Alaska Airlines Alaska Airlines Alaska Airlines Alaska Airlines Alaska Airlines Alaska Airlines 

25         25              25              25              25              25 

25         25              25              25              25              25 

125        125             125             125             125             125 

155        155             155             155             155             155 

Ooof       Ooof            Ooof            Ooof            Ooof            Ooof 

Delta      Delta           Delta           Delta           Delta           Delta 

25         25              25              25              25              25 

35         35              35              35              35              35 

200        200             200             200             200             200 

150        150             150             150             150             150 

We Lost Track We Lost Track   We Lost Track   We Lost Track   We Lost Track   We Lost Track 

United     United          United          United          United          United 

25         25              25              25              25              25 

35         35              35              35              35              35 

200        200             200             200             200             200 

250        250             250             250             250             250 

Whaaaaat?  Whaaaaat?       Whaaaaat?       Whaaaaat?       Whaaaaat?       Whaaaaat? 

Am. Airlines Am. Airlines    Am. Airlines    Am. Airlines    Am. Airlines    Am. Airlines 

25         25              25              25              25              25 

35         35              35              35              35              35 

200        200             200             200             200             200 

205        205             205             205             205             205 

Arrrgh!    Arrrgh!         Arrrgh!         Arrrgh!         Arrrgh!         Arrrgh! 

Spirit     Spirit          Spirit          Spirit          Spirit          Spirit 

30         30              30              30              30              30 

40         40              40              40              40              40 

100        100             100             100             100             100 

292        292             292             292             292             292 

Really??   Really??        Really??        Really??        Really??        Really?? 



===================================================
```

how do I fix it that it would  turn out like this.

Southwest   0    0    0    0   Yes !

Jetblue     20   35   75   125 Yikes!

and so on and so forth.

Comment: There are some more problems in your code. But please offer the first 5 lines of your `fees.txt`.

Comment: first five lines are ' Southwest, 0 , 0, 0, 0 '